# How to enable check of the items of a Listview in Windows Phone?

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have been searching on how to enable check of the items of a Listview on windowsphone 8.1, but I can't find any documentation.
Could you suggest me a solution? I want to succeed something similar to the images below.

[image: Items unchecked]
[image: Items checked]

Comment: I guess you are looking for selectionmode property of listview

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how I could use it like the image examples above?
I want the selection boxes to be hidden and appear if the user taps on the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the selectionmode property as none and when the multiselect appbar is clicked set the selectionmode property of that listview as single or multiple

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works, but how could I make the selection boxes to be hidden and appear if the user taps on the left side of a list item?

Comment: That was possible with longlistselector control of windows phone 8(silverlight) which is not available for winRT app. So way around would be to have a button or border inside the listitem that changes the selection mode property of the listview when clicked or tapped.